# Almost empty symfony install ( missing vendors except for flex )

Tags: symfony, installation

```
symfony new my-project
```

is supposed to install a basic working symfony app but it gives me a project that's almost empty, with only `composer.json`, `composer.lock` and a `vendor` directory with only `symfony/flex`.

`composer.json` does include `symfony/framework-bundle`, but the bundle is not in vendors.

Running `composer install` does not do anything, and doesn't give an error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Installing `php-zip` solved it for me (required by composer).

Looks like it might not be installed by default on recent ubuntu php installations, and either composer or the symfony binary failed silently.

```
sudo apt install php-zip
# now install vendors
composer update
```